# uasort bad performance sorting an array of object with custom order

Tags: php, arrays, performance, sorting

I have to sort an array of objects called "contents", made like this:

```
"articles" => array:106 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 467823568
    "title" => "my tittle"
    "data" => "my data"
    "category" => 23
    "order" => 2
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 46782356433
    "title" => "my tittle 2"
    "data" => "my data 2"
    "category" => 25
    "order" => 1
  ]
  ...
]
```

The order is defined in 2 array, `category_o` and `order_o` made like this:

```
"category_o" => array:21 [▼
      0 => 25
      1 => 95
      2 => 135
      3 => 72
      4 => 4
      5 => 23
      6 => 7
      7 => 803
      ...
]
```

I would like to have articles sorted by property "category" with a custom order specified in `category_o` array, and then a second sort by property "order" with the other custom order specified in `order_o`.

To sort articles I use `uasort` method:

```
// Call sort function
uasort($articles,  array($this, "sortByCategoryOrder"));
```

with my custom function `sortByCategoryOrder($left, $right);`:

```
function sortByCategoryOrder($leftItem, $rightItem){
    // Array that contains order
    $order = $this->category_o; 
    // Exchange key with value, so we can access "position by value"
    $flipped = array_flip($order); 
    // Init default value for position
    $rightPos = 0;
    $leftPos = 0;

    // Check if order of current category is present:
    // the $category_o array could not have all order
    // values of articles
    if ( (array_key_exists($leftItem["category"], $flipped)) && (array_key_exists($rightItem["category"], $flipped)) ){
      // NO MISSING: the 2 element have order
      $leftPos = $flipped[$leftItem["category"]];
      $rightPos = $flipped[$rightItem["category"]];

    }else if (array_key_exists($leftItem["category"], $flipped)) {
        // MISS RIGHT: the right elmenet has not custom order specified! 
        $leftPos = $flipped[$leftItem["category"]];
        $rightPos = $leftPos+1;

    }else if (array_key_exists($rightItem["category"], $flipped)){
        // MISS LEFT: the left elmenet has not custom order specified! 
        $rightPos = $flipped[$rightItem["category"]];
        $leftPos = $rightPos+1;        

    }else{
        // MISS LEFT AND RIGHT: the 2 articles have no custom order specified!            
        $rightPos = 99999;
        $leftPos = 99999;
    }

    // Make the comparation
    return $leftPos >= $rightPos;   
}
```

I have a second function called `sortByOrder($left, $right);` that sort articles by `order_o` array values.

It takes around **12 seconds** to sort ca. 2000 articles.
Is `uasort` realy slow or have I made some mistake in my custom order functions?
Thanks

---

**THE SOLUTION:**

I've found right solution thanks to @Ahmad Hajjar.

I wrote another method that set for each content the new property `category_o` and `order_o` and use a **double natural ascending order** with the php's method `array_multisort()`.
Performance increase and with the current **2000 articles** pass **from ca. 9 secs to ca. 1 secs**!

I report my new method, hope it will be hopeful:

```
public function sortArticles($articles, $type)
{
    // init sorted
    $sorted = array();

    // Array that contains order
    $order_c = $this->category_o; 
    // Exchange key with value, so we can access "position by value"
    $flipped_c = array_flip($order_c); 

    // Array that contains order
    $order_o = $this->order_o; 
    // Exchange key with value, so we can access "position by value"
    $flipped_o = array_flip($order_o); 

    // Iterate each article
    foreach ($articles as $article) {

        // If custom order was specified set it to article
        // Otherwise, set 99999 value.
        if ( array_key_exists( $article["category"], $flipped_c) ){
            $article["category_o"] = $flipped_c[$article["category"]];
        }else{
            $article["category_o"] =  99999;
        }

        // If custom order was specified set it to article
        // Otherwise, set 99999 value.
        if ( array_key_exists($article["order"], $flipped_o) ){
            $article["order_o"] =  $flipped_o[$article["order"]];
        }else{
            $article["order_o"] =  99999;
        }

        // Push new article inside array
        array_push($sorted, $article);
    }

    // get a list of sort columns and their data to pass to array_multisort
    $sort = array();
    foreach($sorted as $key => $value) {
        $sort['order_o'][$key] = $value['order_o'];
        $sort['category_o'][$key] = $value['category_o'];
    }

    // Determinate order type, category or order
    if (strcmp($type, "category") == 0) {
        // sort by category_o asc and then order_o asc
        array_multisort($sort['category_o'], SORT_ASC, $sort['order_o'], SORT_ASC,$sorted);
    }else{
        // sort by order_o asc and then category_o asc
        array_multisort($sort['order_o'], SORT_ASC, $sort['category_o'], SORT_ASC,$sorted); 
    }

    // Return sorted array
    return $sorted;
}
```

Comment: if articles are stored in a DB why don't get them from the DB sorted by whatever field you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a model design issue. I would go with changing my model to store category_o ranks along with the category values and order_o ranks along with their values, then get them from the DB ordered by whatever you need ... so when you get your array from the DB you get it like this

```
"articles" => array:106 [▼
  0 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 467823568
    "title" => "my tittle"
    "data" => "my data"
    "category" => 23
    "category_o" => 5
    "order" => 2
    "order_o" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 46782356433
    "title" => "my tittle 2"
    "data" => "my data 2"
    "category" => 25
    "category_o" => 0
    "order" => 1
    "order_o" => 2
  ]
  ...
]
```